# Using arrow keys to navigate between sections using scrollTo plugin

Tags: jquery, scrollto, keycode

I know similar questions have been asked, but none seems to solve my dilemma. So here goes!

I have sections on a page I would like to navigate to using the up/down arrow keys. The first one is called "header", whereas the rest are called "module".  I'm having trouble getting the numeric value of "next" to update, let alone the problem with distinguishing between "header" and "module" when scrolling!

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="pages">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="module"></div>
    <div class="module"></div>
    <div class="module"></div>
    <div class="module"></div>
</div>
```

And my JQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {

var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
    arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 },       
    elements = $(".module,.header"),
    next = 0,
    max = elements.length;

switch (keyCode) {
    case arrow.down:
        if(next+1 < max) {
            next++;
            $("#pages").scrollTo(elements[next], 800, { axis:"y" });
            console.log(next);
        }
    break;

    case arrow.up:
        if(next-1 > -1) {
            next--;
            $("#wrap").scrollTo(elements[next], 800, { axis:'y' });
        }
    break;
}

});
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!